# PowerShell Listing different arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have 2 different arrays and when I list them in the script, the columns of the 2nd one, do not appear. If I list them individually, then they list correctly.

For example, when listing in a script, I get this output:

```
Name                       ipaddress    numofconnections
----                       ---------    ----------------
SRV1                      12.2.2.2                0
SRV2                      11.1.1.1                0
vServer1                                              
vServer2
```

If I list each array separately, I get this out:

**Array1**

```
Name                       ipaddress    numofconnections
----                       ---------    ----------------
SRV1                      12.2.2.2                0
SRV2                      11.1.1.1                0
```

**Array2**

```
name                                 curstate
----                                 --------
vServer1                         UP      
vServer2                         DOWN
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I think you shoul explicitly select what particular columns you want to see. `$Array1 | select Name, ipaddress, numofconnections` for each collection. Or `format-table property1, property2, ...`.

Comment: How are you currently trying to list them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use

```
| Out-String
```

for example

```
$array1 | Out-String
$array2 | Out-String
```

then it displays 2 separate tables as in the original post

Comment: Why the down vote. It worked!

Anyway, I needed to format the tables and change the header and followed this article. [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx)

This sorted out my original problem and I didn't need the
    Out-string

Answer (score 0):

I suppose PowerShell takes the first object in the array and displays the properties of it. If another object in the list has more properties, it won't show them.  However, you could iterate over the items and select your columns:

```
$array1, $array2 | Foreach { $_ | select Name, ipaddress, curstate }
```

**Output:**

```
Name     ipaddress curstate
----     --------- --------
SRV1     12.2.2.2          
SRV2     12.1.1.1          
vServer1           UP      
vServer2           DOWN
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell cannot detect the transition between the first and the second array, it just sees a continuous series of objects emitted to the pipeline.

You are probably doing something like this:

```
$array1 = Get-Something
$array2 = Get-SomeOtherThings

$array1 # send to the pipeline
$array2 # send to the pipeline (in this case it will append to the pipeline)
```

When this happens, PowerShell will try to provide a valid display for the objects, and in this case selects a Format-Table layout. This is determined by looking at the first object received, and counting the number of properties to display. Once the display format is choosen, it will use the same format for all objects in the pipeline.

If you wan't to display two different tables, then you will need to let PowerShell know there is a break between the two series.

That's why the [answer by @mattnicola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38342347/62662) works, because it breaks up the pipeline in two parts.

If you wan't full control of the display, then you can do this as well:

```
$array1 | Format-Table  # causes the items in the pipeline being written to console in table layout (no items are emitted to the pipeline after this)

$array2 | Format-Table  # causes a new table to be written to the console.
```